# How to list lex/yacc or flex/bison patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching, bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I would like to extract all patterns from a flex/bison file to look at them altogether. I am not interested in the rules applying to the patterns for now.

Surely someone has written a flex/bison file for this already? :)

Comment: Yacc rules are called 'productions', not 'patterns'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give it the `-v` command-line option, bison will output a nicely formatted version of the grammar (and all the states) to a file with extension `.output`. You can specify the precise file name to write to with `--report-file=PATH` and a list of things to report on with `--report=THINGS`; see `bison --help` for details. But afaik, the grammar is always printed, near the beginning of the report file, just after the list of conflicts, if any.

`flex` does not have an equivalent option, but if you specify the `-T` flag (intended for debugging flex itself), then flex will dump to stderr a list of the patterns, as well as other information of possibly less use. (The output is a little hard to read if you use start condition blocks, and it has macros expanded, which might or might not be what you're looking for.)